# Parsing Bootstrap Datepicker timestamp to Joda DateTime

Tags: javascript, java, jodatime, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I got a timestamp from Boostrap datepicker (TimeRangeService.To exactly):

```
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var selectedDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    TimeRangeService.To = String(selected.timeStamp);
    $('#idTimeRangeFromInput').datepicker('setEndDate', selectedDate);
});
```

I need parse it to Joda DateTime object:

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(fromStr));
```

But every time when I choose any date and send timestamp (parsed to long) in DateTime constructor, I'm getting object with today's date.

Example: I selected 05/12/2017 in datepicker, but after parse, new DateTime object has date 14/12/2017. Any solutions?

Comment: What Long.parseLong(fromStr) is returning in your case?

Comment: Long.parseLong(fromStr) returning normal long variable, because fromStr is a String and DateTime constructor accept long type only

Comment: Agree! those are the milliseconds.But from where does 'fromStr' getting date in code?

Comment: Ah yes, there are miliseconds. fromStr is a TimeRangeService.To value, sended in POST request from frontend. And TimeRangeService.To is a timeStamp from Bootstrap datepicker (see first code example in my question)

Comment: Alright. Please Try  DateTime from = new DateTime(Long.parseLong(fromStr), DateTimeZone.UTC);

Comment: Doesn't work - new DateTime object after creation has date 14/12/2017 (today) but in datepicker i'm selected date 04/12/2017. Datepicker for date 04/12/2017 returns timestamp 1513251547953, but Joda DateTime is created with today date.

Comment: JODA Datetime converted it correctly.For 04/12/2017 Timestamp should be 1492110000000

Comment: Interesting, because TimeRangeService.To value is updated in changeDate event, so will be always correctly. Now i see it's a problem with selected.timeStamp in datepicker.

Comment: To try you can hardcode this timestamp and check. Means issue is when you change value in datepicker "selected.timeStamp" doesn't gets updated value.

Comment: Exactly, you got it right!

Comment: Try var timeStamp = $("#datePickerId").datepicker("getDate").getTime(); to get timestamp of selected Date

Comment: Thanks man! It works! <3

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed, thanks [Hasan Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8744304/hasan-ali) for help!

Use :

```
var timeStamp = $("#datePickerId").datepicker("getDate").getTime();
```

because *selected.timeStamp* variable got a old timestamp. Curiosity, in my case Bootstrap have a interesting problem. Look at this:

```
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var selectedDate = selected.date;
        var timestamp = selected.timeStamp;
        $('#idTimeRangeToInput').datepicker('setStartDate', selectedDate);
      });
```

In this case (event fired every time when user will change data in datepicker) *selected.date* **is correct**, but **selected.timeStamp don't**.